# Writing module for Apache

Tags: c, apache

I wrote a simple module for web server, but I cann't apply the filter for a specific HTTP status. For example, I would like to add a specific header in the response if the response from the server is `200`.

For processing the request I use `ap_hook_fixups`. As the handler of the hook, can get the status of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The fixups phase is the wrong place to do this. It occurs before the request handler is called, so the response (and its status) has not been determined yet.

If your module needs to modify the response after it has been generated, it will need to operate as a filter. You may want to refer to the Apache document [How filters work in Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/filters.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you!
Do not you have any examples of how to get the status?